# TEXTJOIN (IF statement - Array) in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, textjoin

I have a data for which I used TEXTJOIN in excel to achieve the result.

---

The function looks like :

=TEXTJOIN("/", TRUE, IF([id]=[@[id]], [likes], ""))

---

How can I achieve this in Power BI?

In Excel, I converted my data to Table and then hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER (as it's array) to get my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a **Calculated Column** to your table with the following formula:

```
=
VAR ThisID = 'Table'[id]
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[id] = ThisID
        ),
        'Table'[likes],
        "/"
    )
```